# Convert certain numbers which are randomly distributed in a list while leaving others

Tags: python

I have list z, been trying to convert all the 1s to 0s only if they were preceded or followed by 0. The 2s and 4s act as breaks in the sequence, and 1s not attached to 0 should remain 1s. The list y is what I would like to have.

```
z=[2,1,2,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,2,0,1,4,1,0,0,1,1,2,0]
y=[2,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,0]
```

I can only get all the 1s to be 0s including the ones not attached to 0.

```
for a in range(len(z)):
    if a==0: 
        startindex=0
    elif a==(len(z)-1):
        ctr+=1
        for i in range(startindex,(len(z))):
            if z[i]==1:
                f=1
                y.append(f)
            else:
                f=z[i]
                y.append(f)
    else:
        for i in range(startindex,a):
            if z[i]==0:
                f=0
                y.append(f)
            elif z[i]==1: 
                f=0
                y.append(f)
            else:
                f=z[i]
                ctr+=1
                y.append(f)
        startindex=a
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I've tried to fix your indentation, but you still have a couple of undefined variables.  One-letter variable names and no comments make your intended logic unclear.  Please make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks, i'll work on that. The code I wrote essentially just turns all the 1s to 0s, I failed to get only the 1s attached to 0s to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). The idea is, if there is any zero in a sequence of 0 and 1, all will turn to 0, and the other values are left unchanged:

```
from itertools import groupby

z = [2,1,2,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,2,0,1,4,1,0,0,1,1,2,0]

out = []
for zero_or_one, group in groupby(z, lambda x: x in {0, 1}):
    values = list(group)
    if zero_or_one:
        if any(x==0 for x in values):
            values = [0]*len(values)
    out.extend(values)


print(out)
# [2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]

y=[2,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,0]
assert out == y  # this is the expected output
```